# SimpleXML issue with ElementException - no match

Tags: android, xml, simple-framework

Input XML:

```
<DeviceInfo dpId="..." rdsId="..." rdsVer="..." dc="..." mi="..." mc="...">
<additional_info>
<Param name="..." value="..." />
<Param name="..." value="..." />
</additional_info>
</DeviceInfo>
```

Entity DeviceInfo

```
@Root(name="DeviceInfo")
public class DeviceInfo {

        // Mandatory
        @Attribute(name="dpId")
        public String DpId;
        @Attribute(name="rdsId")
        public String RdsId;
        @Attribute(name="rdsVer")
        public String RdsVer;
        @Attribute(name="dc")
        public String Dc;
        @Attribute(name="mi")
        public String Mi;
        @Attribute(name="mc")
        public String Mc;

        @Element (name="additional_info")
        public AdditionalInfo AdditionalInfo;

        // Constructor
        // ...
        // Getter & Setter
        // ...

        public static class AdditionalInfo
        {
            @ElementList(name="Param",entry="Parameters", inline = true)
            public List<DeviceInfoParam> Parameters;

            AdditionalInfo()
            {
            }
        }

        public static class DeviceInfoParam
        {
            @Attribute(name="name")
            public String Name;
            @Attribute(name="value")
            public String Value;

            DeviceInfoParam()
            {
            }
        }

}
```

Issue:
W/System.err: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'Param' does not have a match in class x.x.entities.DeviceInfo$AdditionalInfo at line 3

Question:
What's missing in entity (I cannot change XML!)? I tried all kinds of variations already including element instead of elementlist, adding entry, inline etc.

Comment: And where is `Parameters` entry in your xml? I never used this library but I would do obvious thing... Remove AdditionalInfo at all, instead I would put list directly in deviceinfo with entry=additional_info

Comment: Or rather entry=Param and name=additional_info

Comment: that was just one of many tries ... entry can be removed ... no change ... actual name of the field is param as in xml

Answer (score 0):

in your annotation, you need to add required = false.  This lets it get skipped if there is no match.  For example:

```
@ElementList(name="Param",entry="Parameters", inline = true, required = false)
        public List<DeviceInfoParam> Parameters;
```